# Hide form and show

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

What I'm trying to do is when form2 is opening making the parent form Hide.
That is none issue but when form2 is closed I want to Show the parent form again.

```
   this.Hide();
   ReadFrom form = new ReadFrom();
   form.ShowDialog();
   this.Show();
```

That only flash quickly the parent & it still stays on the screen (windows form not wpf)

Comment: Check this out: [Hiding and showing forms in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11335abc-4346-4b93-9782-c56ce7462e9b/hiding-and-showing-forms-in-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Comment: It looks as though your new ReadFrom frm is immediately unloading itself on load. (Sounds like there is a bug in it.)  Can you show the code for ReadFrom please?

Comment: Closing as typo because OP's self-answer mention the exact same code works after other changes

Answer (score 0):

1st form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReadFrom form = new ReadFrom();
        form.Owner = this;
        this.Hide();
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

2nd form:

```
public partial class ReadFrom : Form
{
    public ReadFrom() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void ReadFrom_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Owner.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do I change "App" to?, I tried project name & it gives me this error:
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Current' does not exist in the namespace 'project20' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is entirely different. `form` is not a modal dialogue anymore and the user can manually show and interact with the parent form, something that is not possible in the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

I swear to god I don't know how but I tried your answer [Toni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10542645/toni) & [Maciej Los](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142028/maciej-los).
Both didn't work.
But it guided me.
I don't know why this works now but it works (might have changed a property by mistake & now it works, dunno)
the code:

```
   this.Hide();
   ReadFrom form = new ReadFrom();
   form.ShowDialog();
   this.Show();
```

Sorry for the inconvenience guys.

Comment: The problem is: `ShowDialog();` I guess, try `Show();` instead.

Comment: It still has the same bug, for a brief moment your app has no window that can get the focus.  So the OS may pick a window of another running app and your window shows up behind it.  You have to make it visible again *before* the dialog disappears, FormClosing event.